# Как изменить цвета строк в таблице

Tags: html, css

Имеется таблица, в которой все столбцы имеют свои стили и раскрашены в разные цвета. 
Каким образом можно "подсветить" некоторые строки таблицы целиком? 
Т.е. все цвета сделать темнее или светлее, чтобы не писать для подсвеченных строк изменённые стили для каждой колонки.

Comment: opacity даёт очень неприятный эффект и делает текст тоже прозрачным и плохочитаемым

Comment: @Isaev, цвета задавать в RGBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуйте полупрозрачность для фона в формате `RGBA`, то есть если у вас есть чёрный цвет в `HEX #000000`, то в формате `RGBA` это будет `(0,0,0,1)`, где последняя цифра это полупрозрачность, в стилях данная реализация будет выглядеть вот так:

```
.class {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.class.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); // Полупрозрачность 50% для фона, не затрагивает текст внутри
}
```

Думаю проблем с передов цвета HEX в RGB не возникнет.

Comment: @MasterAlex, это всё я знаю и полупрозрачным 1х1 пиксельным рисунком заливал. Проблемма немного в другом. У нас имеется TR в нём много TD тегов... Если я задаю прозрачность для TR, ничего не меняется, т.к. TD не прозрачные над ним. Получается снова та же проблемма, что нужно иметь дцать прозрачных стилей для столбцов и ещё дцать не прозрачных? Такой подход мне не нравится. Истина где-то рядом и всё как обычно просто)

Comment: @Isaev, если <td> имеют свой чвет БГ, то при наведении на <tr> задавайте цвет его дочерним <td> 

    tr:hover td{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }

Comment: @Deonis, тогда мы перекрашиваем всю строку в заданный цвет, а нужно, чтобы цвета сохранялись, просто становились чуть светлее/темнее

Comment: @Isaev, а расскажите, каким образом у вас задаётся "дцать" непрозрачных стилей для столбцов, а я вам расскажу, что для этих "дцати" стилей нужно "дцать" прозрачных стилей для наведения. Можете, конечно, реализовать добавление прозрачности на JS, но поверьте, это вариант хуже, чем иметь "дцать" стилей.

Comment: А если вы хотите автоматизировать всё это дело, то можно добавить в проект LESS. В нём есть возможность осветлять цвет с помощью функции lighten, а также можно написать функцию, которая принимает цвет, а на выходе даёт 2 стиля: непрозрачный и прозрачный. но после компиляции на выходе всё равно будет 2 стиля, которые вы не хотите писать руками.

Comment: @Deonis, всё таки сделал через TR.background, но немного иначе. Задал все TD полупрозрачными, а при изменении TR теперь меняются цвета. В принципе работает, но только в опере, в firefox такая подсветка пропадает. Знает кто в чём может быть причина?